# ADODB Recordset.Open giving syntax error excel to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, adodb

I'm toast, cannot figure out why I'm getting a **SYNTAX** error on the line
**rst.Open strSQL**

I've tried it with **rst.Open strSQL, cnt, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText**

But it still gives me an error.

I have a sneaking suspicion it has to do with how strSQL is taking a cell value and appending it to the end of a string.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
   Public Sub EzPz()

Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset


Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset


Dim strSQL As String

'Open connection
cnt.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=HIDDEN;Database=HIDDENXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=HIDDENU;PWD=HIDDENP;"
cnt.Open

'String for SQL cmd
Dim p1 As Range
Set p1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4)
strSQL = "SELECT DBNAME.vItem.Upc FROM DBNAME.vItem WHERE vItem.ItemDesc=" & p1.Value



rst.ActiveConnection = cnt    
rst.Open strSQL

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst

End Sub
```

Comment: Two big problems and your question - two big things 1) you are showing your username and password.  You need to change them them now.  2) you are using string concatination -- this is a security issue any public website will be hacked in hours.  Finally the reason for the error is you don't surround the string value in quotes

Comment: I changed the password and username haha HIDDENU and HIDDENP are not the user & pass :P
does that mean rst.Open "strSQL"

Comment: I'm happy to hear those were not your username and password :)  No -- I meant the actual value for the string constant in the sql needed quotes -- but a number of answers covered that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is subject to SQL injection. You could enclose the string literal in single quotes [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43191236/1188513) to fix the syntax error, but that wouldn't fix the serious security issue.

[Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/)

So how do you *securely* parameterize a query? With *parameterized queries*!

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADOBD.Connection
.ConnectionString = "connection string ideally using Windows Authentication"
.Open
```

Ideally your connection string doesn't contain any username or password; your server needs to be configured to support *Windows Authentication* for this to work - the query then executes with the credentials of the logged-in Windows user, with the privileges *of that user*.

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DBNAME.vItem.Upc FROM DBNAME.vItem WHERE vItem.ItemDesc = ?;"
```

Set up a `Command` object. The `CommandText` will be your SQL statement, but instead of concatenating the parameters into it, you use a `?` question mark for each.

```
Dim itemDesc As ADODB.Parameter
Set itemDesc = New ADODB.Parameter
itemDesc.Type = adVarChar
itemDesc.Direction = adParamInput
itemDesc.Value = p1.Value

cmd.Parameters.Append(itemDesc)
```

Create a `Parameter` for each `?` question mark in the SQL statement. You must supply a parameter for each `?` question mark.

```
Dim results As ADODB.Recordset
Set results = cmd.Execute
```

You obtain the `Recordset` by calling the command's `Execute` method; the server deals with the parameters.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset results
```

If all went well, the `Recordset` contains your results.

Always use parameterized queries: user input concatenated into SQL statements is a plague.

Comment: Hey Mat, thanks for the detailed answer. My approach to building this code is start with barebones and move up from there. I wasn't going to leave the UID and PWD in the connectionstring, setting up windows authentication for my account will take time as it is a corporation.
I will take learnings from your answer about using CommandText and apply them as I build this code out.

Comment: Just saying, the *right* approach is to build your code with security in mind *from the start*. Your current approach is how `Dave O'Brian` can't log on to many websites because his username contains a single quote. Database-access code that uses user input **MUST** be properly parameterized - no ifs, no buts, no excuses.

Comment: Fair. Question for you - I want to cycle through a whole column of ItemDesc and run it through the query, would it be wise to loop running of the query and output and change parameter every time I run the query.

Comment: Absolutely! And guess what, the parameterized query can use the same identical query plan, while the concatenated version will require a recomputation of the query plan every time - parameterized isn't only safer, it should also be faster.

Answer (score 2):

SQL needs to understand string literals as such; you need to delimit string literals with single quotes for the syntax to be valid.

Can you try this to see if that works?

```
strSQL = "SELECT DBNAME.vItem.Upc FROM DBNAME.vItem WHERE vItem.ItemDesc= '" & p1.Value & "'"
```

Comment: solved it. 
Now I have an error to access the SELECT statement, but that I'll speak to my admin about :D!

Comment: @Mjall2 keep the checkmark where it is if you want, but I urge you to at least *read* my answer.

Comment: @Mjall2 I agree with Mat's Mug here. You should go through his in depth answer he has provided.